# Mulesoft: How to map and group data with same key in mule 4 dataweave 2.0

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft

**I could transform my input with for each and sum filter value to get output format (many data will be add in an array). But it took a much time with for each. How I can map it with transform message for faster? Please help me some key to solve it.**

**My Input:**

```
{
  "PART_NUMBER": "501-239",
  "HUBS": [
    {
      "NAME": "SUK",
      "SUB_INVENTORIES": [
        {
          "NAME": "FG",
          "LOCATORS": [
            {
              "NAME": "FGACCESSORY"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "NAME": "SUK",
      "SUB_INVENTORIES": [
        {
          "NAME": "FG",
          "LOCATORS": [
            {
              "NAME": "FGPB"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "NAME": "SUK",
      "SUB_INVENTORIES": [
        {
          "NAME": "RAWWIP",
          "LOCATORS": [
            {
              "NAME": "FLOOR"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "NAME": "SUK",
      "SUB_INVENTORIES": [
        {
          "NAME": "RAWWIP",
          "LOCATORS": [
            {
              "NAME": "VANTAGE"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "NAME": "SUS",
      "SUB_INVENTORIES": [
        {
          "NAME": "FG",
          "LOCATORS": [
            {
              "NAME": "FGACCESSORY"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "NAME": "SUS",
      "SUB_INVENTORIES": [
        {
          "NAME": "FG",
          "LOCATORS": [
            {
              "NAME": "FGPB"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "NAME": "SUS",
      "SUB_INVENTORIES": [
        {
          "NAME": "RAWWIP",
          "LOCATORS": [
            {
              "NAME": "FLOOR"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "NAME": "SUS",
      "SUB_INVENTORIES": [
        {
          "NAME": "RAWWIP",
          "LOCATORS": [
            {
              "NAME": "VANTAGE"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**Expected output:(I need to group all hub and all sub_inventories with same name)**

```
 {
   "PART_NUMBER": "501-239",
   "HUBS": [
     {
       "NAME": "SUK",
       "SUB_INVENTORIES": [
         {
           "NAME": "FG",
           "LOCATORS": [
             {
               "NAME": "FGACCESSORY"
             },
             {
               "NAME": "FGPB"
             }
           ]
         },
         {
           "NAME": "RAWWIP",
           "LOCATORS": [
             {
               "NAME": "FLOOR"
             },
             {
               "NAME": "VANTAGE"
             }
           ]
         }
       ]
     },
     {
       "NAME": "SUS",
       "SUB_INVENTORIES": [
         {
           "NAME": "FG",
           "LOCATORS": [
             {
               "NAME": "FGACCESSORY"
             },
             {
               "NAME": "FGPB"
             }
           ]
         },
         {
           "NAME": "RAWWIP",
           "LOCATORS": [
             {
               "NAME": "FLOOR"
             },
             {
               "NAME": "VANTAGE"
             }
           ]
         }
       ]
     }
   ]
 }
```

**Please give me some advice!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/dw
---
do {
    var hubs = payload.HUBS groupBy $.NAME
    ---
    {
        PART_NUMBER: payload.PART_NUMBER,
        HUBS: (
            hubs mapObject do {
                var subs = flatten($.*SUB_INVENTORIES) groupBy $.NAME
                ---
                {($$): {
                    NAME: $$,
                    SUB_INVENTORIES: (
                        subs mapObject do {
                            var locs = flatten($.*LOCATORS)
                            ---
                            {($$): {
                                NAME: $$,
                                LOCATORS: locs
                            }}
                        }
                    ) pluck $
                }}
            }
        ) pluck $
    }
}
```

There got to be a better way to do this as compared to what I did--i.e. I don't like nesting the same expression (for the most part) three times.  I just can't see it yet and I spend enough time on this :).

I hope it helps.